# Why am I getting 'Application Error' when deploying to Heroku? (MERN app)

Tags: heroku

I've checked the logs and this is what it says:
[image]

Here is my app.js file (at the root level):

```
// Importing frameworks, libraries, routes, and JSON parser 
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const rewards = require('./routes/api/rewards');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

// Loading static build folder for production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
  })
}

// Create a new Express server
const app = express();

// Setup middleware for body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Import MongoDB key
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB using Mongoose
mongoose
  .connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Create basic express routing
app.use('/api/rewards', rewards);

// Determining which port to run on
// Deploying on Heroku requires the server to be on process.env.PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;  

// Start a socket and listen for connections on the path
// Display a success message when server is running correctly
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

Any pointers/tips on what this error message is saying exactly? My best guess is that it has something to with one of my routes but I'm not too sure...

Comment: are you trying to deploy react app?

Comment: Yes, and I'm using MongoDB as well

Comment: please edit your post and show your server.js or app.js code.

Comment: Sure, let me add that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making your app variable below your if of production check to serve react build.

please move line

```
const app = express();
```

above your if check.

correct app.js would be:

```
// Importing frameworks, libraries, routes, and JSON parser 
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const rewards = require('./routes/api/rewards');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

// Create a new Express server
const app = express();

// Loading static build folder for production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
  })
}   

// Setup middleware for body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Import MongoDB key
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB using Mongoose
mongoose
  .connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Create basic express routing
app.use('/api/rewards', rewards);

// Determining which port to run on
// Deploying on Heroku requires the server to be on process.env.PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;  

// Start a socket and listen for connections on the path
// Display a success message when server is running correctly
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```